# Metamask: Logged into an existing account with seed phrase and changed the password

Tags: metamask

I have 2 computers with Metamask installed in Chrome (main computer and backup computer). Both had different accounts.

Now I wanted to use Uniswap with the funds of my backup computer's MetaMask while using my main computer. I entered the seed phrase and in the process also changed the password.

My problem is that I logged myself out of the Metamask on the main computer and I don't have the seed phrase for this one. The password obviously no longer works since the Metamask is now associated with the other account and the changed password.

Is there any way to get access back for the Metamask that was active on the main computer? I know the password and I tried the trick of decrypting the vault, however, it only shows me the seed phrase of the account that is now active in Chrome.

Your help is much appreciated!

Thanks a lot